# Do I need any resistors on the outputs of my optocouplers?

Tags: transistors, bjt, opto-isolator

I came up with this circuit:

[image: schematics]

The idea is that I have this resistor ladder at the left that creates 8 different voltages between 0 and 24 V and I have 8 optocouplers that can switch one of these voltages through to the voltage follower op-amp. Only one will be on at the same time. "All off" or "multiple on" are not expected states but can surely happen by unplugging the connector or because of software bugs, etc.

My question is about the outputs of the optocouplers, as I am not very familiar with the behavior of BJTs. Do I need any resistors to pull them up when they are not illuminated? And do they need a minimum load or something to show the correct voltage?

Comment: My understanding is that there are photocurrents produced at the "base" and that current needs to flow from the base to emitter so current can flow from collector to emitter. I could be wrong though. A large resistor from opamp pin 3 to ground should do it. You also need a shared current limiting resistor for the LEDs on the opto inputs.

Comment: You don't appear to need optical isolation at all since you have a common ground. Given the op-amp ultra low input current the configuration you have will not work since the leakage current for the upper level optos' will dominate. Explain what you are trying to do to get further help.

Comment: @JackCreasey I think the optos are more for the  high-high-high-high side drive of the BJTs.

Comment: @DKNguyen It is completely unnecessary to have the high voltage chain unless the output is radiometric relative to 24V. You'd normally set the gain of an Op-amp to get your desired output voltage from a reference. That could be done with a few FETs.

Comment: @JackCreasey GND and GNDS are different grounds and they are completely separated unless I made a mistake?

Comment: @AndreKR, sure you have GND and GNDS, but you still don't appear to need 8 channels of opto-isolation. Explain what you are trying to do, and what needs isolation.

Comment: @JackCreasey On the left side I have a microcontroller, probably an ESP32. On the right side I have a heater that is controlled by a voltage between 0 and 24 V, relative to its power supply. This was the easiest way I could come up with to control it, since I don't know if for example PWM will upset it.

Comment: @AndrewKR A heater? Heaters are perfectly okay with PWM! In fact they are traditionally controlled with really really really slow PWM, think 0.01Hz, but can be faster if needed.

Comment: Look at a CD4051 or equivalent for some alternative ideas.

Comment: PWM probably ok. || PWM via one opto with filtering gives analog.|| 3 optos to CD4051 gives 8 channel analog selector. Opamp can scale low voltage range up to desired voltage.

Comment: @user253751 Not just a heating element. A heater with a whole bunch of control electronics that interprets the voltage.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon CD4051 can't run off 24 V, so I need a regulator. 8 couplers seems simpler than 3 couplers + CD4051 + power supply.

Comment: This can be easily done with just a few components if you use DAC (e.g LTC2630) or digital pot (e.g. MCP4011). SPI is very easy to isolate with either discrete optics or multichannel chip. Note that digital pot may not even require buffer, depending on input impedance.

Comment: @Maple A digipot was my very first idea but I couldn't find an available one that can do 24 V.

Comment: Well, then don't put it on 24V. Add external resistor on top and use buffer with required gain

Comment: @Maple I'd still have to power it without breaking it. If there were isolated digipots I could power it from the MCU side, but I don't think there are.

Comment: @AndreKR  - As above, you can run the 4051 on a lower supply and scale up Vout with the opamp. Current should be minimal allowing a simple R + zener supply. Given the choice, if PWM and filtering doesn't suit, I'd not consider the CD4051 or equivalent solution more complex. || PWM with a simple RC single pole filter may suffice. Using a 3 pile Bessel low pass with one opamp section (or even just a single transistor) would produce a low ripple fast response filter. I have used 3 pole LP Bessel on a number of occasions where I wanted both low ripple and reasonable response.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon But I *have* no lower supply and adding a power supply to the circuit appears to make it so much more complicated than any other solution.

Comment: @AndreKR. Your choice. 12v is one zener and a resistor and a cap off 24v. 4051 output can scale up  via opamp. || Check ability of opamp to reach high rail. With a pullup and light load 358 MAY be good enough. 358's Voh is about 2 to 3 v below V+ at 24V. Pullup helps as then opamp is pulling down against pullup. MAY need a rail-rail amp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Do I need any resistors on the outputs of my optocouplers?

The question is moot, since the schematic you show will not work.

1. The opto-isolator you use is NOT rated for Veco (reverse voltage across the CE pins, so reverse biasing them is an unknown.
   The reverse rating of most bipolar transistors is complex and depends on the Si architecture. Typically the reverse CE rating is the same as the reverse BE rating.
   Here [is the datasheet](https://www.marktechopto.com/pdf/products/datasheet/MTD8600NT_2011_07_19.pdf) for a Si opto-transistor, MTD8600N showing the limiting voltage.
   [image]

Where the opto-transistor is a Darlington pair (not your case I know), the limitation may be less than 0.6V Veco as shown [here](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/us/semiconductor/knowledge/faq/opto/opto-019.html) by Toshiba.
In your schematic, you expose most of the opto-transistors to a high Veco, while they may not break, they will certainly destroy any hope of a predictable output voltage from you op-amp.

2. The LM358 will not reach 24V output for two reasons. Firstly the output driver is about two emitter drops from Vcc, and secondly the input is rated at Vcc - 1.5V.

Perhaps the output and input voltage limitations are workable for you, but I'd strongly suggest a rail-rail capable op-amp such as the TLV9351 for your application.

3. Using 8 channels seems like a severe over usage, you can get by with just 4 channels and achieve your goal.

Perhaps an approach such as this may work for you:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPJOco.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Notice above there is a 3bit digital value plus an OFF value. Off will be very close to Vout=0 and the maximum does not quite reach 24V. If you want ratio-metric output, then swap D1 for a resistor of appropriate value.
No reverse bias on the opto-isolators and always a positive current flow for those turned on.
I did not calculate the input resistors for the opto inputs, but you should split the required value with half on this side and half on the MCU side to provide some protection for wrong connections.

Comment: 1. Good point about the voltage, using some gain at the op-amp seems like a good solution. 2. I noticed that as well and because some datasheet said running the op-amp outside it's output voltage range "could lead to increased power consumption" I added one resistor at the top and one at the bottom. I don't need the full range, something between 4 and 20 V is fine. 3. I thought about that too, but I have a tight power budget on the MCU side and this would require me to light up multiple LEDs at the same time.

Comment: @AndreKR, since the current required on the output transistor is low....the input current to the LED is also low. You could scale this to a much lower current, I didn't attempt to do so. In the end having multiple LEDs (max 3) on with perhaps only 0.3mA or so LED current would seem quite easy to achieve. To be more brutal, I would never do this application in this manner, I simply provided a similar architecture to your original idea (which would not work) for you to think about.

Comment: Oh, so in an optocoupler you don't run the LEDs with a typical LED current but you take the desired output current and the inverse current transfer ratio to calculate the input current?

Comment: @AndreKR ...exactly.

Comment: Thanks, with your help I have made [this simulation](https://tinyurl.com/yf57uyrl) that seems to indicate that the circuit might actually work when I build it.

Answer (score 0):

Your plan is ok but...

- The current flowing from the resistor ladder through the bipolar transistor is very similar to current flowing through a diode - current won't flow backwards out.
- The "+" input on your op amp doesn't let any current to flow into it.

These two points mean, you have created a charge trap or a peak detector.  There is no path to ground for the current between emitter and op amp. You'll need some size resistor from "+" to ground. I'll let you determine the resistor size.

The LED side of the opto isolators need a current limiting resistor in series with your signal unless there is current limiting before the signal travels through the 9-pin J? Connector.

Comment: A high value like 1M would be ok to "empty out" the trap without skewing the voltage too much?

Comment: Are you sure the optocouplers act as diodes here? I know that bipolar transistors have a reverse active mode.

Comment: An emitter on a phototransister is no different than a regular bipolar transistor's emitter.  The collector/emitter "dark current" is 1nA according to the Fairchild datasheet.  The input bias current to the LM358 is 40 nA.  

Luckily, there is not much capacitance to hold a voltage as the nA-level current drains but, I would recommend a 1M resistor from "+" input of the opAmp to ground.